# Wirecast to wirecast

Tags: streaming, software, live

I am running a broadcast and would like to include content from 2 locations, each location has the ability to stream from wirecast.

Is it possible to stream from wirecast at location 1 to wirecast at location 2?

Comment: How far away are your "locations" from each other? How much switching between the two locations do you want? For instance, go live in one location for an hour and then go live from the other the second hour ... I need to know some more details.

Comment: One will be from the south of England and one will be from Dublin Ireland.

Comment: What is your CDN for delivery? YouTube, Livestream?

Comment: Looking at having a few changes from between 5 and 30 mins

Comment: Going out to uStream, ideally want the broadcast contained to a single URL

Comment: Of course it's all about a single URL. Is there a reason for using uStream? YouTube is free and really awesome because it's YouTube. It offers 1080 streaming with all sorts of lower resolution options for the viewer with just one broadcast stream on your end. We recently dropped Livestream and uStream for similar reasons. In YouTube you can stream two, or more, Wirecast streams to the same "event" or rtmp and set them as "cameras." Then you can switch between them in the back end.

Comment: Another idea is to stream, let's say, the event in Dublin to a MacBook Pro in England. Then take the HDMI out of that Mac Book (in full screen) and hook it up to your Wirecast in England and boom! You got your two events in one Wirecast with smooth mixing and graphics! Not too shabby of an idea!

Comment: Let me know how it works ... In theory it's a great solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use skype from the remote location into the local computer running wirecast then use their screen capturing option to capture the skype video.

The pro version of wirecast allows and input to be RTMP, Web streams and IP cameras. Assuming you have that, you could stream from the remote wirecast and bring it in as a source on the local system.

You may already be aware, but this will add a major delay in the remote feed. Because it will have to be encoded twice. Once from there to local then again locally on your main feed. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: Personally I would stream a private YouTube event to a local MacBook pro and take the HDMI out (in full screen) and reroute into Wirecast via a Blackmagic micro recorder as a second camera to mix seamlessly with the other feed.  Skype is clunky and not optimal in my experience.